# Typical pitfalls to avoid for BASH beginners.

Tags: bash, scripting

The other day I answered a question where it was necessary to loop through all the sub-dictionaries in a given directory.

As a self-taught bash user I quickly answered the question. However, in my answer I used `for DIR in $(find ...); do "something"; done` to loop through the sub-directories. A polite bash guru pointed out that if I continue with bad habits like that will one day find myself in a lot of trouble.

While correcting my answer I found that I had (embarrassingly) many more bad habits. I could not find any topic like this on stackoverflow, but I am sure there are many people like me at a "beginner(++)" level with bad habits based on methods that "sort-of-works".

**My question is generic albeit simple:**

What are important/damaging pitfalls to avoid for someone who is using bash? *(If you find the question to generic to answer I would appreciate a short description of the case with link to documentation or another SO question regarding the subject is appreciated.)*

E.g. When performing loops to edit files/dirs, using globb characters, pipes, logicals, short hand notation (i.e. ``` `` ```) and **last but not least** applying functions for purposes which they should not be used.

Comment: See the http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide, the http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ, and http://www.shellcheck.net/ . I can't say for certain but I would guess that many of the high voted bash tagged questions have solid answers (and if not will have comments about why).

Comment: Here's one, perhaps a generalization of your `find` example: although it is traditional for shell scripts to perform all sorts of data manipulation via external programs, `bash` can perform many such manipulations internally.  Launching external programs is comparatively costly; it should be avoided where unneeded.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls is also a good place to start (I strongly recommend Etan's links; this one is perhaps even more directly on-point). Frankly, though, StackOverflow isn't a good place for this kind of question (which doesn't have a canonical answer).

Comment: Thank you for the input, "mywiki" is added to bookmarks :) I certainly acknowledge the criticism of the question, Charles, both for your reason and because at the end of the day it all boils down to reading the manual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Google's Styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml) very instructive. I changed some old habits after reading it, and it has a lot of examples.

EDIT: Some points to watch beneath.

- Working with variables: set value without $ and access with $
  Avoid confusion by using ${..} when using the variable
- Calling a command within your commandline with $()
  The old syntax `` will work but you can make easy mistakes.
- Avoid arrays
  You normally do not really need them and they have a more difficult syntax
- Start (first line) your script with `#!/bin/bash`
  It will check and use bash when available and give an error when it is missing.
- Learn regex
  sed can become your close friend. Even when you only use `-e 's/.../.../g'`
  Also other utilities use regex.
- Use the case statement when checking against different possible values
  Avoid too much if-then-else nesting
- Do not skip the if keyword when testing with [[ .. ]]
  The if statement is obsolete but easier to read
- Do not use eval
  When you finally understand the syntax you wil learn it is dangereous.
- Shell builtin's are faster but more difficult to read
  basename is a simple utility but slower than ${fullfile##*/}
  Maybe you should store a note with some handy builtins somewhere.
- Downwards compatible?
  When you think your scripts might have to be migrated to Solaris/AIX with ksh someday, try avoiding bash-specific syntax and Linux utilities. That would be quite difficult (the -i flag in sed, additional options in find) so getting bash installed on Solaris/AIX might be a better way.

Question: ``` E.g. When performing loops to edit files/dirs, using globb characters, pipes, logicals, short hand notation (i.e. ``) and last but not least applying functions for purposes which they should not be used. ```

- When you have a lot of scripts using the same functions, store the functions in a file like common.h
  Include this file with `. common.h`
- Learn the difference between `function xxx {..}` and `xxx() {..}`
- Use local var's and return values by stdout or the returnvalue

Comment: Some of it is good, some of it is not so good. But you don't really answer the question. The question is about pitfalls to avoid, not about style.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Esoteric Sigve stated: `If you find the question to generic to answer I would appreciate a short description of the case with link to documentation or another SO question regarding the subject is appreciated.)`. He asked for a link, you are correct that I should add some highlights.
I will add some points to watch.